C++ Metaprogramning: accessing compile-time static class member from a CRTP c
How do I access a static constexpr inline variable from a CRTP-type class?
It beats me as to why T::X is not available in struct Templated?
template <typename T> struct Templated {
    static const int x = T::X;
};

struct Normal : Templated<Normal> {
    static constexpr const inline int X = 0;
};

Error:

'X' is not a member of Normal.


You have a circular dependency on an incomplete type. So basically your painting yourself in a corner

Despite the comments above which make sense, gcc accepts it. See demo.

It's just a meaningless, simplifed distilled example. About as simple as I can make it. Don't read anything into whether it makes sense or not, guys! Thanks.

@wohlstad I've seen quite different behaviors with compilers and templates. AFAIK older versions of MSVC would also accept it. But with 19 that has been "hardenend" much more of the template code seems to be compiled more early

Try initialising x outside of Templated.

You can move the definition of Templated<T>::x out of the class definition to solve the issue at hand:
template <class T>
struct Templated {
    static const int x;
};

template<class T>
const int Templated<T>::x = T::X;

All the major compilers agree: Demo

delays initialization?  Personally I don't like static variables intemplates like this. If they can not be changed, because it looks like there some fiasco may be happening.

@Swift-FridayPie I don't see how this case would require any extra consern compared to other globals, like Normal::X.

The solution to MSVC not compiling this is to delay the evaluation of T::x, by simply putting it inside a function:
static constexpr const inline int X() noexcept { return T::X }


Did you check if it result in static initialization? If , for some real use-cases you end up with dynamic, there can me moments where static variable is uninitialized.

@Swift I'm pretty sure there is no UB in constexpr in C++. It works and passes UBSan, when implemented as the solution.

UBSan as a clang feature? Mostly, yeah. Depends on details.  wasn't you using MSVC too? It gave me some unpleasant surprised to to implementation quality with initialization. But in this particualr case it was correct not to compile original code. use of Koenig lookup is a workaround, a hack based on fact that we actually shouldn't call any function in resultng code. Which works with vs19, but had issues with earlier versions. With newer C++ you also can use deduced this

Yeh, I must admit I also compiled it in Apple Clang and Linux GCC, just to be sure! I don't think UBSan is available on 'doze. Just address sanitizer ...

The code is ill-formed regardless it compiles or not - Normal is incomplete at
point of Templated<Normal> use, so use of any types or variables defined in Normal is not legal. Possible solutions would be use of a member
function or a template function with argument-dependent name lookup, which requires templates to be located in a namespace, or separating definition from 'Normal'.
template <typename T> struct TemplatedDefs;

template <typename T> 
struct Templated : TemplatedDefs<T> 
{
    static const int x = TemplatedDefs<T>::X;
};

struct Normal;
template <> 
struct TemplatedDefs<Normal> {
   static constexpr const inline int X = 0;
};

// TemplatedDefs<Normal> is complete
struct Normal : Templated<Normal> {
   
};

This pattern is commonly used in libraries with CRTP, even in olderimplementations of standard C++ library. Definition of "user" class requires adding an auxilary definition. Class TemplatedDefs<Normal> can also house type definitions specific for Normal to be used in Templated. Another possible solution is not linking Template to particular class at all and passing "definitions" class to it as argument, leaving to Templated the task of creating an instance of it, where requred.
template <typename T, typename N> 
struct Templated 
{
    static const int x = N::X; 
};

struct TemplatedDefs {
   static constexpr const inline int X = 0;
};

struct Normal : Templated<Normal,TemplatedDefs> { 
};

PS. Some versions of MSVC largely ignore ADL limitation of not being possible with types and functions defined in global namespace. Porting code with ADL to GCC may give surprises.
